# github actions create release via API

Tags: api, github, github-actions, release

Here is a github workflow that I would like to use to create a release.

```
name: make release

on: 
  workflow_dispatch:


jobs:
  try-to-create-a-tag:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      
    steps:
      - name: Create release
        run: curl \
               -X POST \
               -H "Accept:application/vnd.github+json" \
               -H "Authorization:token ${ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }" \
               https://api.github.com/repos/.../releases \
               -d '{"tag_name":"tag_test11","target_commitish":"main","name":"tag_test11","body":"Description of the release","draft":false,"prerelease":false,"generate_release_notes":false}'
```

The workflow runs without error, however I get the following message from curl:
`authorization:token ${ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }: bad substitution`

I have also tried using double braces, however this didn't work either. How can I substitute the variable into the curl command?

NOTE: the error is that one must use a `|` right after `run:` when splitting over multiple lines.

Comment: Did you try using a PAT instead of the default GITHUB_TOKEN? Something like this: `${{ secrets.PAT }}`

Comment: I specifically want to use the GITHUB_TOKEN as this is the correct way to access the API as far as I am aware.

Comment: Using double braces is correct. Please try again and post the exact error. Furthermore, avoid using secrets directly in `run` steps and instead use `env:\n TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}` and then use `${{ env.TOKEN }}`, because otherwise your secret will be visible to other processes.

Comment: Also, since you're running on `ubuntu-latest`, consider using [gh](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/using-github-cli-in-workflows) to make your code simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use double brackets:
`${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}`

Documentation:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#example-using-bash

```
jobs:
  try-to-create-a-tag:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      
    steps:
      - name: Create release
        run: |
            curl \
            -X POST \
            -H "Accept:application/vnd.github+json" \
            -H "Authorization:token ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
            https://api.github.com/repos/.../releases \
            -d '{"tag_name":"tag_test11","target_commitish":"main","name":"tag_test11","body":"Description of the release","draft":false,"prerelease":false,"generate_release_notes":false}'
```

Comment: as I just added as a note in my post, another error is that I didn't put the `|` after the `run:`. This is required when splitting a command over multiple lines. Could you add this to your answer so as to make this more obvious to anyone who might encounter this post? In any case, thanks for your answer to my question.